# Getting error when I am trying to setup the WinRM in Windows 2012 R2 using AWS user data with terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to setup the WinRM using the below code.

```
$url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"
$file = "$env:temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1"

(New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $file)

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File $file
```

I am trying to install in windows 2012 R2 EC2 machine. When I tried it manually running the script in the machine, it worked. When I try to run the same code in AWS console while launching the EC2 and added user data it worked.

But same code when I am trying to run it from Terraform as a user data bootstrap. I am getting the below error.

```
2020-02-29T13:08:25.375Z: Ec2HandleUserData: Message: The errors from user scripts: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "Unable to connect to 
the remote server"
At C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Scripts\UserScript.ps1:7 char:3
+   (New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $file)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

The argument 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
```

Comment: Hi Uma, welcome to SO. You will want to read over the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section and actually post the smallest terraform example to reproduce that behavior, since there is no way one can **guess** what is wrong with your script

Comment: Hi Mdaniel, thanks for your quick response. But I have solved issue, using packer and terraform, the below links are helped me to solve the issue.   https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/14953   https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15571 I believe we can close this issue. Thanks!